# Simple react nextjs landing page shows not secure connection in production causing the loading time to be very long

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a very simple react app with next.js. What could be the reason for seeing connection is not secure and (I think) leading to very long loading times (sometimes up to 30 seconds? This doesnt always happen but I would say 6 /10 times. Also it happens after deploying it, not in development. Thank you.

Comment: You probably would not be having SSL on your prod environment

Comment: Do I need to add that? How would I do that?

Comment: It depends on where you are deploying. Then do a google search on how to add ssl to "your deployment cloud"

Comment: I have the website deployed at render.com. I have followed all the steps it should be, if I understand correctly, be taken care of without me adding anything

Comment: https://community.render.com/t/why-is-it-showing-the-connection-for-this-site-is-not-secure/8104

https://community.render.com/t/ssl-error-got-to-put-something-here/3315/12

These can help